# json_decode returning NULL [{},{}]

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm pulling information from our database (entered with GLua) with PHP, then using json_decode to change it to an array to work with but it's returning NULL, whereas other ones are working?

```
// Get the RapSheet info from 'character_data_store'
$rap = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `character_data_store` WHERE `character_id` = '$srp_uid' AND `key`='RapSheet'");
while($rapsheet=mysql_fetch_assoc($rap)){
    $raps = $rapsheet['value'];
};
```

Then I use

```
// Deal with the rapsheet JSON
echo $raps;
$raps = json_decode($rapsheet, true);
echo var_dump($raps, TRUE);
```

The echo's are to check that it's working, the information is being pulled successfully as it echos, although the var_dump returns

> NULL bool(true)

Database contents:

```
[{"ArrestedBy":"James Scott","Date":1483732483,"Duration":60,"LeaveReason":"Jail time served.","ArrestReason":"test"}]
```

Any help will be appreciated!

---

**After trying Darren's response:**

---

I tried

```
$rap = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `character_data_store` WHERE `character_id` = '$srp_uid' AND `key`='RapSheet'");
$raps = array();
    while($rapsheet=mysql_fetch_assoc($rap)){
    $raps[] = $rapsheet['value'];
};

// encode
$rap = json_encode($raps, TRUE);
echo $rap;
```

And that returned:

> ["[{\"ArrestedBy\":\"James Scott\",\"Date\":1483732483,\"Duration\":60,\"LeaveReason\":\"Jail time served.\",\"ArrestReason\":\"test\"}]"]
>   So I tried

```
echo $rap['ArrestedBy'];
```

and it returned

> [

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access variables that aren't within the proper scope. `$rapsheet` is only ever accessible within your `while() {...` loop as it will be that current row of data. What you want to do is create `$raps` as an array and insert the lines within it. From there you'll be able to `json_decode()` as you please. Depending on how many rows you've got, you may need to loop over `$raps` and decode each array element.

```
$raps = array();
while($rapsheet=mysql_fetch_assoc($rap)){
    $raps[] = $rapsheet['value'];
};

// encode
$rap = json_encode($raps, TRUE);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but I still can't get it to work :(

$rap = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `character_data_store` WHERE `character_id` = '$srp_uid' AND `key`='RapSheet'");
 $raps = array();
  while($rapsheet=mysql_fetch_assoc($rap)){
  $raps[] = $rapsheet['value'];
  echo $raps['ArrestedBy'];
 };

Comment: Please keep your code in your answer (*not the comments haha*). What didn't work?

Comment: Hi sorry Darren, not usually a stackoverflow person! Also, it doesn't echo anything :/

Comment: @JamesScott Are you sure your sql query is actually returning anything?

Comment: I've edited the post with more information about trying your answer.

Comment: @james sorry it should be `json_decode()` not encode !